# Sql Server 2008/SSIS: Transfer Sql Server Objects Failing, No Useful Debug Information Generated

Tags: ssis

I am trying to copy a Sql Server 2008 database from a production server to a development server. I set up a new empty target database, and added a Transfer Sql Server Objects task to the Control Flow pane. I configured the task to use SMOServer connections (both of which test fine). I've tried both copying all objects and copying just the ones I want. I've set it to drop destination objects first, even though there's nothing in the target database.

Yet it refuses to work. And it generates absolutely no error information at all, despite the fact that I have tried to turn on every logging option I can find. All I get is success in the validation phase, a series of warnings that certain classes of objects don't exist to copy (which is correct), followed by a "hang" in the "yellow zone" (i.e., the task box is highlighted in yellow).

How in the world can something as simple, straightforward, and frequently done as copying a database be so darn difficult? What am I doing wrong? Besides using SSIS, I mean :).

p.s. Sigh. Every time -- every time -- I try to use SSIS to do something that should be drop-dead simple it ends up being a royal PITA. IMHO it's one of the worst-written pieces of development software Microsoft has ever inflicted on the world. I wish whoever is in charge of it in Redmond would come sit next to me one of these times...so he could experience the heat of 10,000 suns worth of anger and frustration :).

**Edit:**

In response to Diego's feedback, I should've mentioned that I don't have sysadmin rights on the server where the source database is. It's on a 3rd party hosting service.

Also, my "workaround" for this problem involved doing an Import Data from within SqlServer Management Studio on the target server. That's not a good workaround -- it leaves out all the keys, triggers, sprocs, etc -- but it at least got my core data across.

But I ran into a problem there, too, because I was using "non integrated security" on the source server but integrated security on the destination/target server. There's nothing in the wizard to point out a problem doing things that way, but it turns out it'll cause the SSIS package that gets generated to fail. The security approaches have to match on both "ends" of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes 10,000 suns isnt enough :)
I understand your frustation, SSIS can be really dificult to deal with in sertain situations, but it is a very powerfull tool .

Anyway, I would tell you to start by checking permissions. I had issues with it before where I was moving logins with the "drop destination objects first" selected and my user didnt have permission to create logins, so they were droped first and when it was time to recreate them, the package failed, leaving my instance without logins and locking me out of SQL.

Really frustrating situation, I would have written something on the component to check, before the deletion, if I had permissions to create the objects preventing this kind of situations.

yeah, anyway, try to run your package with a sys admin user for example

Comment: Thanks, good advice. Unfortunately the source database in this case is on a server where I don't have sys admin permissions (probably should've mentioned that; I'll edit my questions).

Comment: I dont think the source is the problem, since you are creating the objects on the destination, you would need privileges on the destination.